# Assembly: How does fld st(0) duplicates the top stack value in the following code?

Tags: assembly, x86, x87

In the following code, I am wondering about the role of `fld ST(0)`. I have heard it duplicates the top value in the stack but I don't know where does it bring that value in the following code?

```
fild    dword ptr [L1000F140]
fstp    qword ptr [esp+20h]
fld ST(0)
fdiv    qword ptr [L1000F148]
fmul    qword ptr [L1000A520]
```

My interpret is that code above in symbolic way means:

```
value[esp+20h]= value[L1000F140]
new stack top value=value[esp+20h]/value[L1000F148]*value[L1000A520]
```

Am I correct?

I wonder why `fstp` does not pop the loaded value so `fld` has duplicated `value[L1000F140]` it?

Comment: Is this the entire code?

Comment: I'm sure it's not.  :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good [guide to x87 FPU](http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/index.html) by Raymond Filiatreault.  [Chapter 1](http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap1.htm) explains how the FPU register stack works.

Yes, `fld st(0)` pushes a copy of the top of the stack.  The Intel insn ref manual explicitly mentions this special-case use of `fld st(n)`

I believe you're right that `fstp` does pop after the `fild`.

- The first `fild / fstp` pair converts a global `int` (at L1000F140) to a float on the stack.
- Then `fld st(0)` duplicates the top of the stack (i.e. the value that was there before the `fild/fstp`).
- Then divide that value by another global, and multiply by another.
- final stack:

```
st(0)=orig / global1 * global2
st(1)=orig
```